# A question about Graph Coloring theory

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am studying graph theory. I cannot find a the name of the theorem which applies here:

Suppose we have this undirected graph below:

[image: undirected graph]

My argument is that since there are odd cycles A-B-C-A and even cycles A-B-D-C-A therefore this graph will need four-coloring.

However, the texts I have consulted so far say that "an undirected graph cannot have an odd and even cycles at the same time".

Where am I going wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Take the graph composed of two disjoint cycles, one even, one odd. Clearly, this graph is 3-colorable. "an undirected graph cannot have an odd and even cycles at the same time" This is completely wrong, where did you read that?

Comment: Here,your graph needs for colors because it is a 4-clique (a graph with 4 vertices connected 2 by 2), and each vertex needs to be colored differently.